# 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR en React y Flask

Tags: python, reactjs

Estoy programando una funcionalidad en mi aplicación de React la cual permite convertir un video de youtube a formato de mp4. Para esto uso un servidor con python y Flask. Pero cuando envio por POST la url a convertir me sale este error y eso que añadi flask-cors para evitar el problema con los dos servidores

Codigo Python

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import pafy

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

@app.route('/convertidormp4', methods=['POST'])

def ConvertidorMp4():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = pafy.new(request.form['url'])
        best = video.getbest(preftype='mp4')
        best.download()
        return 'video convertido'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Codigo React

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';



export const Convertidor = () => {
      const [url, setUrl] = useState("")

      const handlersSubmit = async (e) =>{
          e.preventDefault()
          await fetch('/convertidormp4',{
              method: 'POST'
           })
       } 

    return(
     <>   
      <h2>ConvertidorMp4</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handlersSubmit}>
        <input 
         type="url" 
         name="url"
         value={url}
         onChange={(e)=> setUrl(e.target.value)}
         placeholder="url del video a convertir" 
         />
         <button>Convertir</button>
      </form>
      </>
     
    );
}
```

Comment: un error 500 significa que ha ocurrido una excepción en tu servidor Flask. Para diagnosticarlo habría que ver el mensaje de esa excepción. Ya que has usado debug=True el propio navegador debería mostrarte el stactkrace, y hasta permitirte depurarlo desde el navegador (puedes abrir una especie de "terminal" en el servidor e inspeccionar variables del marco de pila cuando se produjo la excepción)

Comment: ya he intentado de todo y todavia el error

Comment: No sé si conoces alguna otra forma de unir esta dos tecnologías

Comment: "todavía el error" ¿qué error? No nos has dado esa información. Decir error 500 es como decir "no funciona". Insisto en que el servidor Flask tiene que estar mostrando en algún sitio un _stacktrace_ que muestra qué excepción ocurrió y en qué línea del código.

Comment: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'url'